# Manipulate Slope

Tags: manipulate

this is my code:

```
f[x_] := 1 - 2 x + x^2;    
tangent[f_, a_] := f[a] + f'[a] (x - a)    
slope[x_] := f'[x]      
sol = x /. Solve[tangent[f, 2] == tangent[f, 3], x] // N          
sol[[1]]              
f[2.5] // N 

Plot[{f[x], tangent[f, 2], tangent[f, 3]}, {x, 0, 4}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{2.5, 2.25}]}]

Manipulate[Plot[{f[x], tangent[f, t], tangent[f, t + 0.1]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{2.5, 2.25}]}], {{t, 4,"time"}, 0, 4, 0.05}]
```

The red point dont' move together the lines.

I fixed my code, but my notebook flash now.

```
Manipulate[  Module[{x}, f[x_] := 1 - 2 x + x^2; 
  tangent[f_, a_] := f[a] + f'[a] (x - a);
  slope[x_] := f'[x]  ;
  sol = x /. NSolve[tangent[f, t] == tangent[f, t + 1], x]; 
  resul = sol /. sol -> sol[[1]];
  Plot[{f[x], tangent[f, t], tangent[f, t + 1]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{resul, f[resul]}]}]]
 , {{t, 4, "tiempo"}, 0, 4, 0.05}]
```

Comment: `Point[{2.5, 2.25}]` specifies a constant location, so it wouldn't move with the lines. You probably want to start there.

Comment: You may want to use `NSolve[...]` instead of `Solve[...] // N`.

Comment: How fit the code Point[{2.5, 2.25}]}] to dynamic

Answer (score 2):

Finally this is my ultimate code

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Module[{x = x1},
 f[x_] := 3.87 + 0.98 Exp[-(x/166)^0.72] + 1.15 Exp[-(x/7255)^0.75];
 tangent[x_, a_] := f[a] + f'[a] (x - a);

 Manipulate[
  interx = 
   Ceiling[x1 /. NSolve[tangent[x1, t] == tangent[x1, t + dt], x1]] //
     Simplify;
        localization = {interx, tangent[interx, t + dt]} // Flatten;
  p1 = Graphics[{Dashed, Thick, 
     Line[{{0, tangent[interx, t + dt][[1]]}, {interx[[1]], 
        tangent[interx, t + dt][[1]]}, {interx[[1]], 0}}]}];
  p2 = Graphics[{Dashed, Thick, Line[{{0, f[t]}, {t, f[t]}, {t, 0}}]}];
  p1textsX = {Style[Text[t, {t + 1000, f[t] + 0.03}], Bold, 14]};
  p2textsX = {Style[
     Text[interx[[1]], {interx[[1]] + 1130, 
       tangent[interx, t + dt][[1]] + 0.01}], Bold, 14]};
  title = 
   Style[Text[
     "Δm = slope 2 (green) - slope 1 (yellow) ", {17000,
       4.95}], Italic, Bold, 14];
  pend = EngineeringForm[f'[interx[[1]]] - f'[t], 3];
  m = Style[Text[HoldForm[Δm] == pend , {19590, 4.85}], 
    Bold, 14];

  Show[{Plot[{f[x1], tangent[x1, t], tangent[x1, t + dt]}, {x1, 0, 
      25000}, PlotRange -> {{0., 25000.}, {3.96, 5.}}, 
     Epilog -> {title, m, p1textsX, p2textsX , Black, 
       PointSize[0.015], Point[{t, f[t]}], Point[localization]}, 
     AxesStyle -> Thick], p1, p2, 
    Plot[f[x1], {x1, 3000, 10000}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]}, 
   ImageSize -> Large], {{t, 2500, "Red Zone (t)"}, 2500, 10000, 10, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{dt, 10, "Slope Angle (dt)"}, 10, 10000,
    10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the position of the red point dynamically, just make it depend on the `Manipulate` variables appropriately, for example:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x], tangent[f, t], tangent[f, t + 0.1]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{t, f[t]}]}],
   {{t, 4, "time"}, 0, 4, 0.05}]
```

Specifically, focus on `Point[{t, f[t]}]`. It seems that the intent is to highlight point of contact between the function and the tangent line, so we need to input that point as where the `Point` will be positioned. It should be obvious that `{t, f[t]}` will be a point on the plot of the function `f`. We also know that `t` is the `x`-position of the tangent intercept, so that's the point we're interested in. So just plug that point into `Point`.

The output is essentially equivalent to @m_goldberg's answer.

Comment: grateful for everything

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[f, tangent]
f[x_] := 1 - 2 x + x^2;
tangent[x_, a_] := f[a] + f'[a] (x - a)

Manipulate[Plot[{f[x], tangent[x, t], tangent[x, t + 0.1]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
  Mesh -> {{t}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-5, 10}}], {{t, 2.5, "time"}, 0, 4, 0.05}]
```

[image]

Comment: grateful for everything

Comment: @Andres, glad you found it useful. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_] := 1 - 2 x + x^2;
tangent[f_, x_, a_] := f[a] + f'[a] (x - a)
isectx = x /. 
   First@Solve[tangent[f, x, t] == tangent[f, x, t + 1], x] // Simplify
dotloc[t_] = {isectx, f[isectx]}
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x], tangent[f, x, t], tangent[f, x, t + 1]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> {-15, 15},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@dotloc[t]}], {{t, 4, "time"},
   0, 4, 0.05}]
```